Content Download speed is too slow on Digital Ocean Droplet using Nginx for reverse proxy
I have a node server (Cube JS: https://github.com/cube-js/cube) deployed on Digital Ocean Droplet served through PM2,Using Nginx for reverse proxy.

Tested on 15mb network

Content download speed goes as low as 20kb per second sometimes.
Normally I get 150kb to 200kb speed.
I have a suspicion that compression might be throttling the speed. But my dataset dataset has more than 50k rows I cannot go without it.
Is there any better and faster compression technique?
Why do I get some down times on this? is this normal on digital ocean droplet?
How can I  improve this speed from 150kb to something better?
Will upgrading droplet help?
My Droplet Configuration is as follows:

Nginx Configuration:

user www-data; worker_processes auto; pid /run/nginx.pid; include
/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on; }

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 8;
    gzip_buffers 64 2k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss
text/javascript;




    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##



    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; }


